# Facebook Feed Dialog in Native Facebook App Browser Missing Share/Post Button

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Facebook Javascript SDK to bring up a feed dialog, which allows the user to post to their wall. This is working perfectly in iOS Safari but not so well when inside the Facebook app's browser. Inside of Facebook's in-app browser, the feed dialog is missing the Share button that normally appears at the top right corner of the overlay. I have attached a screenshot to illustrate. I have been grinding my gears on Google trying to find people with similar issues but have not been successful. Have you had any similar experiences? Does this look like a bug with Facebook or something that I am doing wrong. If it is the latter, can you shed some light on how I might go about fixing? Thanks!

[image: pic of Facebook feed dialog inside of native Facebook app's browser]